# A Date Class with simple methods

Tags: c++, datetime, homework

This is homework from one MOOC(no requirement of forbidding paste codes online). 
The title gave me a framework:

```
class Date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};
```

And it asks me to implement `operator<()`, `operator>()`, `operator==()`, as well as `print()` and `sort()`.

Below codes is my implementation:

```
/*=============================================================*/

//date.h

#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H
#include <iostream>
class Date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    static char colon;
public:
    Date(int m, int d, int y) : month(m), day{d}, year{y} {}
    bool operator>(Date const& another) const { return this->magic() > another.magic(); };
    bool operator<(Date const& another) const { return this->magic() < another.magic(); }
    bool operator==(Date const& another) const { return this->magic() == another.magic(); }
    void print() const { std::cout << year << colon<< month << colon << day << std::endl; }
    long int magic() const { return static_cast<long int>(month * 100 + day + year * 10000); }
};
#endif // !DATE_H


/*=============================================================*/

//date.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "date.h"
char Date::colon = '-';

/*=============================================================*/

//extras.hh

#ifndef EXTRAS_HH
#define EXTRAS_HH
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "date.h"
#include "extras.hxx"
inline void description();
inline void checkValid(int month, int day, int year);
inline auto generateDate();
inline void Sort(std::vector<Date>& v);
inline void print(std::vector<Date>& Dates);
#endif


/*=============================================================*/

//extras.hxx
//To use inline and seperate inline functions' declaration and definition

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "date.h"
struct InvalidDate {};
inline void description()
{
    std::cout
        << "Request: " << std::endl
        << "  (1): CreatePoints: generates Dates;" << std::endl
        << "  (2): Sort: sort the dates" << std::endl
        << "I will check if dates generated by rand() is valid, such as LeapYear"
        << std::endl
        << std::endl;
}
inline void checkValid(const int month, const int day, const int year) noexcept(false) 
{
    if (day > 31 || month > 12 || day <= 0 || month <= 0 || year < 0) 
    {
        std::cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << ": " << "day > 31 || month > 12 || day <= 0 || month <= 0 || year < 0 is not valid? " << std::endl;
        throw InvalidDate();
        return;
    }

    if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && day == 31)
    {
        std::cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << ": " << "it is a solar month of 30 days" << std::endl;
        throw InvalidDate();
    }

    if (month == 2)
    {
        if ((year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0) || year % 400 == 0)
        {
            if (day > 29)
            {
                std::cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << ": " << "is LeapYear!!" << std::endl;
                throw InvalidDate();
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (day > 28)
            {
                std::cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << ": " << "is LeapYear!!" << std::endl;
                throw InvalidDate();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

inline auto generateDate() noexcept(false) 
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    std::vector<Date> ans;
    int month = 0, day =0, year = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        month = std::rand() % 15, day = std::rand() % 35, year = std::rand() % 10000;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                checkValid(month, day, year);
            }
            catch (InvalidDate)
            {
                month = std::rand() % 15, day = std::rand() % 35, year = std::rand() % 10000;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        ans.push_back(Date( month, day, year ));
    }
    return ans;
}

inline void Sort(std::vector<Date>& v)
{
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](Date const& a, Date const& b) { return a < b; });
}

inline void print(std::vector<Date>& dates) 
{
    for (auto date : dates) date.print();
}

/*=============================================================*/

//Main.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "extras.hh"
#include "date.h"
int main()
{ 
    description();
    std::vector<Date> dates = generateDate();
    Sort(dates);
    print(dates);
}
```

Here is a sample output in console

```
Request:
  (1): CreatePoints: generates Dates;
  (2): Sort: sort the dates
I will check if dates generated by rand() is valid, such as LeapYear

8/0/3339: day > 31 || month > 12 || day <= 0 || month <= 0 || year < 0 is not valid?
14/33/2889: day > 31 || month > 12 || day <= 0 || month <= 0 || year < 0 is not valid?
0/19/3260: day > 31 || month > 12 || day <= 0 || month <= 0 || year < 0 is not valid?
0/12/8402: day > 31 || month > 12 || day <= 0 || month <= 0 || year < 0 is not valid?
778-8-6
1679-12-15
2029-8-28
2614-5-10
4645-6-2
4913-12-3
5253-3-7
8024-4-3
9589-5-26
9632-11-4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I enhance these codes? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Zeta it seems vs2017 accept the two colons and compiles lol. Now I have fixed.

Comment: Ah, that's fine. I was talking about the variable's name.

Comment: Instead of Magic() maybe use [Current Day Epoch](https://www.epochconverter.com/daynumbers) (or, more specifically, [this post](http://disq.us/p/f8al48)).

Comment: @WernerCD thanks, it's like two judgments(day and year)  have to be made and may be influenced by leap year.

Comment: It doesn't have a time zone. This is suicide in practice when working with temporal data. When you get into the real work force, *never* try to write something like this yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## What's in the public interface?

Most of the public interface looks reasonable, except it's not obvious what `Date::magic()` means to a user - I think that's more useful as a private method.

The `print()` method is inflexible, as it will only write to `std::cout` - users are out of luck if they want to write to `std::cerr` or to a `std::ostringstream`, for instance.  Consider instead a more idiomatic print function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Date&);
```

(You'll need to include `<iosfwd>` to declare `std::ostream`.)

## Range checking should be part of the class

The `check_valid()` method logically belongs to the `Date` class; it probably makes sense for it to be called as part of the constructor:

```
    /* more intuitive order of arguments! */
    Date(int year, int month, int day)
        : month{month}, day{day}, year{year}
    {
        checkValid();
    }

private:
    void checkValid() const
    {
          if (month <= 0 || month > 12)
              throw std::domain_error("month");
          // etc
    }
```

## Use an array of month lengths

Instead of the unwieldy test `(month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && day == 31)`, we could use a table of month lengths.  Something like

```
static const int month_length[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30,
                                    31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
auto max_day = month_length[month-1];  // we've already checked 0 < month <= 12
if (month == 2 && is_leap_year(year))
    ++max_day;

if (day <= 0 || day > max_day)
    throw std::domain_error("day");
```

## Consider `std::tuple` comparison

Instead of creating a collation key using the `magic()` function (which probably wants a better name, but hey, naming is hard), it's possible to compare the fields in turn by combining them as a tuple:

```
bool operator<(Date const& other) const
{
    return std::make_tuple(year, month, day)
         < std::make_tuple(other.year, other.month, other.day);
}
```

Consider using `std::rel_ops` to save writing the other relational operators by hand (you missed `<=`, `>=` and `!=`, for example).

## Pass by const reference where possible

The `print(vector)` implementation can benefit from a couple of `const` declarations and `auto&` rather than `auto`:

```
inline void print(std::vector<Date> const& dates) 
{
    for (auto const& date: dates)
         date.print();
}
```

## Finally

```
char Date::colon = '-';
```

That's the most misleading name I've seen for a while - I suggest `field_separator` or even just `separator` as an alternative.  Given that it's class scope (i.e. `static`), it probably ought to be `const`, or you risk weird bugs at a distance.

Comment: thanks! But maybe you mean std::ostream &write(std::ostream &dest) const {...}. operator<< can't be member function : )

Comment: @czxyl, thanks for spotting that - I should have tested!

Comment: Ah, another small problem is static array month_length ranges from 0 to 11 while month above is 1 to 12, I have added 666 as the placeholder to the first element.

Comment: your solution to check_valid quite inspires me a lot and other suggestions adhere me to many aspects which I nerve paid attention to. Thanks for codereview.com and Toby Speight and others who review my codes. HAPPY!

Comment: I fixed the off-by one, using `month-1` to index; I think that's cleaner

Comment: Agree. Another problem about design I just came across is if I throw the exception in the constructor, I have to catch the exception in generateDate()'s while loop. If the date is invalid, it's ok, just continue, but as soon as the date is valid, try block will just release the valid object because of RAII. How can I solve the problem elegantly?

Comment: Not sure (and I have to leave now).  One option is to have the concept of an 'invalid' date object (that's what Qt does) and to not insist that dates must be valid.  Or a separate validation method, and tell users it's UB to operate on values that don't pass.  Or something like `while (true) { try { ans.push_back(Date(/*args*/); break; } catch(std::domain_error) {/*repeat until success*/} }`  I suggest you try a few alternatives, and perhaps even post another review with one or more options.

Answer (score 8):

> And it asks me to implement operator<, operator>, operator==, as well as print and sort dates.

Only going to review these parts.

---

```
    bool operator>(Date const& another) const { return this->magic() > another.magic(); };
    bool operator<(Date const& another) const { return this->magic() < another.magic(); }
    bool operator==(Date const& another) const { return this->magic() == another.magic(); }
    long int magic() const { return static_cast<long int>(month * 100 + day + year * 10000); }
```

Should `magic` be publicly exposed?

Prefixing `this->` is implied.  Typically used in objects you maintain, so as long as you avoid shadowing names, you shouldn't need to prefix `this->` and can reduce clutter.

Don't weigh your `Date` members for ordering.  Lexicographically compare your `Date` data members.  That means you should find the first mismatching data member and then apply the comparison operator.  C++11 makes this simple by using [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) (requires `<tuple>`) on the data members to create a [`tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), then using the [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) for `tuple` objects to lexicographically compare.

Using `operator<` and `operator==`, you could implement the remaining 4 relational operators through logic.

```
 a > b ... b < a
a <= b ... !(b < a)
a >= b ... !(a < b)
a != b ... !(a == b)
```

The `tuple` comparison operators are simpler.

```
  private:
    auto tie() const { return std::tie(year, month, day); }

  public:
    bool operator<(Date const& another) const { return tie() < another.tie(); }
    bool operator>(Date const& another) const { return tie() > another.tie(); }
    bool operator==(Date const& another) const { return tie() == another.tie(); }
```

---

```
    void print() const { std::cout << year << colon<< month << colon << day << std::endl; }
```

Writing [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) to a stream is exactly equivalent to writing a `'\n'`, followed by a [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) to a stream.  For buffered streams, manual flushing could have a significant cost compared to automatic flushing.  If you explicitly would like to flush a buffered stream, then stream `std::flush` so readers of your code know flushing was intended.  If you just need a newline, prefer `'\n'`.

---

```
inline void Sort(std::vector<Date>& v)
{
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](Date const& a, Date const& b) { return a < b; });
}
```

Your lambda is equivalent to using [`std::less<Date>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less).  C++14 introduced [transparent operator functors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17737216/3762339), which simply means the type compared is deduced automatically. With C++14, you may omit `Date` from `std::less<>()`.  [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is nice though and uses `operator<` by default if a comparator isn't provided.

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](Date const& a, Date const& b) { return a < b; }); // C++11
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a < b; }); // C++14
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<Date>()); // C++11
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<>()); // C++14
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()); // C++98
```

---

```
inline void print(std::vector<Date>& dates) 
{
    for (auto date : dates) date.print();
}
```

Be consistent with your `const` and reference (`&`) usage.  Did you intend to copy `date` by value or did you intend to reference?  Should the argument be `const`?

Avoid loops without braces.  Braces help make it clear to the reader that there is a block of code present.  Braces also help clearly define the boundaries of a sub-block.

Prefer using a separate line for single-line blocks to simplify setting breakpoints in debuggers.

Comment: Good review - I missed the pointless lambda in sorting.  I've used `make_tuple` where you have `tie`, since the members are primitives and so copying is cheap.  Compiler optimisation will likely lead to the same code for both.